# Send mail with ssmtp without creating a file

Tags: ssmtp

I am able to send an email using ssmtp using the following command line :

```
ssmtp my@email.com < ./textfile.txt
```

...but I want to send a message from a cron task, and on the fly, without creating the file.

I tried

```
ssmtp my@email.com < echo "Text body here..."
```

but that doesn't work. How do I go about getting the above to work?

I also tried

```
echo "Text message..." | ssmtp my@email.com
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
ssmtp my@email.com <( echo "Text body here..." )
```

The <( ) makes the enclosed contents appear as a file descriptor.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the command just goes into input mode.